# Python getting user input errors

Tags: python, user-input

I have a simple program that prompts user to enter number between 1-9 and if the number has been entered previously it will ask the user to enter another number. The user has 10 tries or attempts.

This is only part of what I wanted to do but I am having problems passing the parameter from the getNum method to the method that calls it.  If I enter the number between 1-9, it has no problem. The problem starts when I entered the number previously entered and the prompts ask for another number.

```
def getNum(numList):
    num = input("Pick your number: ")

    if num <= 0 or num >9:
        print 'Invalid number. Please try again.'
        getNum()

    if num in numList:
        print 'Number taken. Please try again.'
        getNum()

    else: 
        return num  

inputList = []
endGame = True
choice = 0  
attempts = 0 
while endGame == False or attempts < 10:

    userNum = getNum(inputList)
    print 'Number entered:', userNum
    inputList.append(userNum)
    print inputList

    attempts += 1
```

Can anyone let me know what I did wrong here?

Comment: Using recursion for the input is not the way to do this. Using `input` is another flaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
return getNum(numList)
```

instead of

```
getNum(numList)
```

in the `getNum` function. The reason is that you call the `getNum` function recursively, thus you have to return the accepted value back through all recursions you made. Additionally, you must pass the arguments to each call.

Answer (score 0):

the way you are calling getNum()  in  "if conditions" is wrong
it should be:-

```
if num <= 0 or num >9:
    print 'Invalid number. Please try again.'
    getNum(numList)

if num in numList:
    print 'Number taken. Please try again.'
    getNum(numList)
```

Answer (score 0):

A complete solution without the dangers of `input`, error handling and no problem with a recursion limit.

```
def get_num(num_list):
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(raw_input('Pick your number: '))
        except ValueError:
            print('Not a number')
        else:
            if 0 < num <= 9:
                if not num in num_list:
                    return num
                else:
                    print('Number taken.')
            else:
                print('Invalid number.')

number_list = []
for _ in range(5):
    number = get_num(number_list)
    print('Number entered: {}'.format(number))
    number_list.append(number)
```